# Running Node.js file in FTP remote server

Tags: node.js, server, ftp, winscp

Im trying to run my application on remote server that i have username and password for. Btw, website works local.

Im using WinSCP to upload files on remote server from local computer. What I do is start session on WinSCP, I choose option ftp, fill out hostname, username, port number. I can successfully connect, but cant find solution for runing website, cant find terminal there.

I tried  typing in PowerShell:  <kbd>ssh your_username@host_ip_address</kbd>
but i get error

> Permission denied (publickey).

then i installed putty, and try to open in it, but putty also doesnt work.
Ive seen some questions where I am suppose to generate public_key and save it in authorized_keys or id_rsa folder, but there are not such thing in my .ssh folder

Is it posibble to run my JavaScript application with FTP remote server or am I using wrong file transfer protocol (should switch from WinSCP)?

Comment: If what you want in the end is to host your JavaScript application and reach it via a browser, then FTP will not be enough. You will need HTTP to query/interact with your JavaScript application. You will need a Web server, not only an FTP server.

Comment: So what should i do next? what would be the next step i need to take?

Comment: You should setup a web server on the machine you are accessing. How to do this entirely depends on the machine itself and what access type you have. It might not be doable, for example if the server is hosted on a cloud service that will only allow FTP access.